# Best way to Handle Exception Globally in Node.js with Express 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, node.js, express

AS We have Exception filter in asp.net MVC, do we have similar kind of functionality in node.js with express 4 also?

I have tried following articles but didn't find the desired solution.

http://www.nodewiz.biz/nodejs-error-handling-pattern/

I have also tried below on app.js

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

ref article: http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 42):

Errors might came from and caught in various locations thus it's recommended to handle errors in a centralized object that handles all types of errors. For example, error might occurs in the following places:

1.Express middleware in case of SYNC error in a web request

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
//call handler here
});
```

2.CRON jobs (scheduled tasks)

3.Your initialization script

4.Testing code

5.Uncaught error from somewhere

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
 errorManagement.handler.handleError(error);
 if(!errorManagement.handler.isTrustedError(error))
 process.exit(1)
});
```

6.Unhandled promise rejection

```
 process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p){
   //call handler here
});
```

---

Then when you catch errors, pass them to a centralized error handler:

```
    module.exports.handler = new errorHandler();

function errorHandler(){
    this.handleError = function (error) {
        return logger.logError(err).then(sendMailToAdminIfCritical).then(saveInOpsQueueIfCritical).then(determineIfOperationalError);
    }
```

---

**For more information [read bullet 4' here](http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practices-of-node-js-error-handling/) (+ other best practices and more than 35 quotes and code examples)**

Answer (score 10):

In express, it's standard practice to have a catch all error handler attached.
A barebones error handler would look like

```
// Handle errors
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (! err) {
        return next();
    }

    res.status(500);
    res.send('500: Internal server error');
});
```

Along with this, you will need to catch errors anywhere they can happen and pass them as a param in `next()`. This will make sure that the catch all handler catches the errors.

Comment: As i already search on google and find this solution  till now in express but I'm looking find out something like exception filter of asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1):

To add global exceptions handlers in node are events on [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html). Use `process.on` to catch them.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
   console.log('whoops! there was an error');
});
```

Comment: it does not catch exceptions globally.

Comment: @AshishKumar: What errors are you getting that you are trying to catch?

Comment: If any exception occurs in the whole application, then it should handle from one place. as we do in asp.net mvc using exception filter.

Comment: Yeah, it should handle uncaught exceptions instead of completely crashing the application...

Answer (score 0):

Express js v4 globally error handling.

```js
app.use((_req,_res,next)=>{
    const error = new Error("Not Found")
    error.status= 404;
    next(error)
})

app.use((error,_req,res,_next)=>{
    if(error.status){
        return res.status(error.status).json({
            message:error.message,
        })
    }

    res.status(500).json({message:'something wrong'})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use((_req, _res, next) => {
    const error = new Error("Not Found")
    error.status = 404;
    next(error)
})

app.use((error, _req, res, _next) => {
    if (error.status) {
        return res.status(error.status).json({
            message:error.message,
        })
    }

    res.status(500).json({ message: 'something wrong' })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Write a middleware to handle like below for all routes in express js

```
function asyncTryCatchMiddleware(handler){
    return async (req,res,next) => {
       try{
           await handler(req,res);
       } catch(e) {
           next(e)
       }
    };
}
```

You can use the middleware like this:

```
router.get('/testapi',asyncTryCatchMiddleware(async (req,res)=>{
    res.send();
}));
```